# streaming video using VideoDisplay in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, videodisplay

i use this tag:

`<mx:VideoDisplay id="myVid" bottom="0" width="100%" height="100%" live="true" autoPlay="true" source="http://localhost:5080/oflaDemo/{myvideo}"/>`

but the only thing i get is the sound of the video and not the video itself,
any ideas???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this happen with every video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="myVid" visible="true" width="100%" height="100%"
                       mediaPlayerStateChange="myVid_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event)">
            <s:source>
                <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="{mediaServerUrl}" streamType="recorded">
                    <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem streamName="../{videoFolder}/{filename}"/>
                </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
            </s:source>
</s:VideoPlayer>
```